# Function argument as __builtin_constant_p?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, move, forward

Is it possible to have a function argument which is __builtin_constant_p?

This macro works fine:

```
#define FOO(a) {\
    static_assert(__builtin_constant_p(a));\
}

void bar() {
    FOO("abc");
}
```

I would like to turn `FOO` into a function. However, this doesn't work:

```
void foo(const char* a) { // how to change argument to make this work?
    static_assert(__builtin_constant_p(a)); // Fails with: Static_assert failed due to requirement '__builtin_constant_p(a)
}

void bar() {
    foo("abc");
}
```

How can I change the argument of `foo` to make it work? Possibly using templates / std::forward or something similar?

Comment: Besides what you show, what else have you tried? You mention templates, did you try to use [non-type template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter)?

Comment: Have you looked at the online docs for __builtin_constant_p? It can be any sort of constant, not just a pointer. It is usually used inside an inline function, in the standard gcc headers, so there are lots of examples of usage.

Comment: Given the `static_assert`, are you wanting to *restrict* `foo`’s argument to be a constant expression?